# Django CommaSeperatedIntegerField and negative numbers

Tags: django-models

If I had the following class:

```
class foo(models.Model):
    list = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length=255)
```

If I try to add a foo object from the admin, it will not let me populate list with negative numbers. For instance, if I populate the field with 1,2,3,4 its fine. But 1,2,3,-4 will give me the error message "Enter only digits separated by commas." Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The validation code of CommaSeparatedIntegerField looks like this:

```
comma_separated_int_list_re = re.compile('^[\d,]+$')
validate_comma_separated_integer_list = RegexValidator(comma_separated_int_list_re, _(u'Enter only digits separated by commas.'), 'invalid')
```

So you can't use it for negative numbers.

I suggest you write your own validation code based on this code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess the next question is: is there an easy way to change the validation code? I don't want to have to create a custom model field.

Comment: You can use a `RegexValidator` on a char field, it will look like: `list = models.CharField(max_length=255, validators=[RegexValidator(YOUR_REGEX_HERE)])`